# Is there a GetTyp / GT2 alternative?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I've used [both tools](http://www.surf.to/phax) since years now, mostly to determine the file types of files which lost their file names because of disk problems.

Unfortunately GetTyp is discontinued, GT2 is no longer actively developed and also lacks some features GetTyp once had:

- Many file types are not detected
- Compilers are no longer detected in GT2 (was in GetTyp)

Is there any alternative to this tool? (Open source, freeware or commercial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the `file` command in the [GNU fileutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/fileutils/)?

It will identify various file formats:

```
$ file track01.cdda.wav 
track01.cdda.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 
  16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
$ file wallpaper2.png 
wallpaper2.png: PNG image data, 1280 x 853, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

It's mainly used on Unix-like systems, but for those unfortunate enough to use MS Windows, there's a port:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

**Edit:**

From the page you linked, GT2 also has some additional functionality such as scanning whole directories/drives, and printing various details about executables.

`file` cannot do this (directly), but there are other helpers available to be combined with it, if you need this functionality (e.g. `find` for dir scanning).